# How is the answer to $5x + 10 = \frac{x}{3} + 24$ obvious without solving the equation or testing any of the choices (multi-choice answer)

Tags: algebra-precalculus

\begin{align*} 
5x + 10 = \frac{x}{3} + 24 \\
(A) 1 \\
(B) 2 \\
(C) 3 \\
(D) 4 \\
(E) 5 \\
\end{align*}
The problem implies that I can deduce the answer $C, 3$ without solving the equation or testing the five choices.
I can't see how.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that all the possibilities are integers, the solution must be divisible by $3$

Comment: Feels so obvious now. Learning the rules and application of methods in maths isn't proving so difficult. But the ability to apply logic and reason improves a little slower. I hope to get a lot better by the time I meet calculus. I'm doing problems until my fingers bleed.

Comment: @Edmund in all fairness, it probably took me longer to think of that than to check for the correct one

Comment: @Edmund You should check out the Art of Problem Solving books, they contain enough problems to make your fingers bleed

Comment: @ me if you find them helpful

Comment: @SomeGuy AOPS is my current resource. I'm on the second book now "Introduction to Algebra". I used Khan academy to complete pre-k-8th grade.

Answer (score 1):

The left side is always an integer because the input answers are also always integers. Thus, the right side must be an integer, and for $\frac x3$ to be an integer, $x$ must be divisible by $3$ as marla stated.